# data is not inserting in my table

Tags: python, mysql, csv

```
import MySQLdb
import csv
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='root', db='kabir')
cursor = mydb.cursor()

data = csv.reader(file('data.csv'))

#cursor.execute('create table actors(name varchar(20),age integer)')                                                                                                                                                               
for row in data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO actors(name,age) VALUES(%s %s)' ,row)
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: Did you try closing the DB: ``mydb.close()``?

Comment: @ChristianAichinger Though it's a good catch, but it's not the problem here..kindly check the answer below.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "load.py", line 13, in <module>
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO actors(name,age) VALUES(%s, %s)' ,row)    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: @user3505729 I think the first row in the csv file it the columns title which in case of the "age" column is not an integer so it give you an error that it can't insert a String into an integer column in the database. Can you please paste the csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify a comma between %s and %s. Change it to:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO actors(name,age) VALUES(%s, %s)' ,row)
```

and try..

Comment: @kabir I think the first row in the csv file it the columns title which in case of the "age" column is not an integer so it give you an error that it can't insert a String into an integer column in the database. Can you please paste the csv file?

Comment: first column is name and second is age

Comment: will header row contain field name in csv file

Comment: @Kabir if it contains the header you should skip it as it will conflict being a string inserting into an integer column. Add:
```data = list(data)[1:]``` after ```data = csv.reader(file('data.csv'))``` which escapes the first line (heading line)

Comment: csv file should start with a heading line then each line contain values separated by commas, so it should be:
```name,age
a,24
b,24
c,52
d,88```

Comment: import MySQLdb
import csv
import numpy as nm
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='root', db='kabir')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
data = csv.reader(file('data.csv'))
data =list(data)[1:]
for row in data:
    row=row[0].split(';')
    row[1]=int(row[1])
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO actors(name,age) VALUES(%s,%s)' ,row)
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
mydb.close()